# Hibernate 6.1: reading UUID from PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am upgrading from Spring Boot 2 to 3, and along with it comes the upgrade from Hibernate 5 to 6.1.

I have a PostgreSQL table containing a UUID column:

```
                            Table "public.combination"
           Column           |   Type    | Collation | Nullable |      Default      
----------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 id                         | uuid      |           | not null | gen_random_uuid()
 kind                       | kind_type |           | not null |
```

I have a JPA model with that column:

```
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "combination")
public class Combination
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NotNull
    private UUID id;

    public UUID getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    ...
```

One record in that table:

```
argas=# select * from combination ;
                  id                  |    kind     
--------------------------------------+---------------
 0f787085-9a45-4512-ae55-f6db24ab8178 | connectivity
(1 rows)
```

I query from that table using a `CrudRepository` subclass:

```
@Repository
public interface CombinationRepository extends CrudRepository<Combination, UUID>
{
    Iterable<Combination> findAllByKind(@NotNull Kind kind);
}
```

In Spring Boot 2/Hibernate 5, the UUID returns correctly as `0f787085-9a45-4512-ae55-f6db24ab8178` (`mostSigBits = 1114764626895389970`, `leastSigBits = -5884525917016194696`).

But after the upgrade to Spring Boot 3/Hibernate 6, the UUID returns as `30663738-3730-3835-2d39-6134352d3435` (`mostSigBits = 3487535676028631093`, `mostSigBits = 3487535676028631093`) - and I really have no idea why or what to do about it.

I use the exact same run configuration, just switching Git branches and rebuilding everything.

I tried already setting `hibernate.type.preferred_uuid_jdbc_type` to either `CHAR` or `BINARY`, but the values returned are the same. PostgreSQL driver version is 42.5.4.

Is this a Hibernate bug? What else can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to reproduce this behavior, I wrote this test:

```java
package org.hibernate;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;
import org.hibernate.testing.orm.junit.DomainModel;
import org.hibernate.testing.orm.junit.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.testing.orm.junit.SessionFactoryScope;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.UUID;

@SessionFactory
@DomainModel(annotatedClasses = UuidTest.It.class)
public class UuidTest {

    @Test
    void testit(SessionFactoryScope scope) {
        scope.inTransaction( s -> s.persist( new It() ) );
        scope.inTransaction( s -> {
            UUID uuid = s.createQuery("select uuid from It", UUID.class).getSingleResult();
            String string = s.createQuery("select str(uuid) from It", String.class).getSingleResult();
            Assertions.assertEquals( string, uuid.toString() );
            System.out.println( string );
        });
    }

    @Entity(name="It")
    public static class It {
        @Id @Generated
        @ColumnDefault("gen_random_uuid()")
        UUID uuid;
    }
}
```

It generates the following DDL:

```sql
    create table It (
        uuid uuid default gen_random_uuid() not null,
        primary key (uuid)
    )
```

which I believe is the same as the schema you have.

It then inserts a row, letting Postgres generate the UUID:

```sql
    insert 
    into It
        default values
    returning uuid
```

It finally asserts that the db's string representation, and Java's string representation are the same. (Of course I also double-checked `psql` on the commandline.)

And everything here looks perfect to me.

I'm not sure what's going on in your case.

**UPDATE:** My point being that it doesn't look like a bug in Hibernate. Of course I have no clue what Spring is doing in all of this.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, it is really appreciated! Do you happen to have an idea how I could diagnose this further on my side?

Comment: I found out that when you set `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` to `false` (which it was in my case), the described erroneuos behaviour occurs. Wit the default value of `true` for this property, it works. Can you confirm?

Comment: Well in principle that makes sense: without the use of JDBC metadata, Hibernate doesn’t know what version of the database you’re using and will assume a “minimum” older version. Note that that property setting is undocumented, unsupported, and not recommended.

Comment: As a workaround, you could try *manually* specifying the database version using the JPA-standard property `jakarta.persistence.database-minor-version`. (But I have not tested this so no guarantees.)

Comment: Well, wait, no, I added `@ServiceRegistry(settings = @Setting(name = "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", value = "false"))` to the test code above, and the test still passes. So perhaps it does not make sense.